# How to add timestamp to Python writelines()?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to add timestamp to writelines() so that I get the timestamp in between the bullet point and the hyphen in the code below:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now()
A = ['ABC', 'PQR', 'XYZ']
f = open("test.dat", 'w')
f.writelines(list(u'\u27B3 - %s\n'.encode('utf-8') % i for i in A))
f.close()
```

**Output**

```
➳ - ABC
➳ - PQR
➳ - XYZ
```

**Desired output**

```
➳ 18:15:02 - ABC
➳ 18:15:02 - PQR
➳ 18:15:02 - XYZ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could import datetime module and concatenate the strings in the appropriate format. Using your own code:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now()
A = ['ABC', 'PQR', 'XYZ']
f = open("test.dat", 'w')
f.writelines(list(u'\u27B3 '.encode('utf-8') + str(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + ' - %s\n' % i for i in A))
f.close()
```